# Ajax post laravel contact form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a few issues with sending ajax to a email.
I need to output the error json as at the moment if i leave a field blank or incorrect it returns "Error: Unprocessable Entity"
The bigger issue i'm having is it's not sending emails and returns a 500 error but if I was to configure it around a bit and only send the name it works fine.

Mail.blade.php
This is in a simple format

```
<h1>{{ $name }}</h1>
<h1>{{ $message }}</h1>
<h1>{{ $email }}</h1>
```

EmailController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Mail;


class EmailController extends Controller {
   public function basic_email(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [ 'name' => 'required', 'email' => 'required|email', 'message' => 'required' ]);
    ContactUS::create($request->all()); 

    Mail::send('emails.mail',
       array(
           'name' => $request->get('name'),
           'email' => $request->get('email'),
           'message' => $request->get('message')
       ), function($message)
   {
       $message->from('test@test.com');
       $message->to('test@test.com', 'Admin')->subject('Feedback');
   });


    return response()->json('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!'); 
   }

}
```

request.php

```
<?php

class ContactFormRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
      return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required',
      ];
    }
}
```

Contact.Blade.PHP

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>

      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

      <script> 
         function getMessage(){

         var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
         var name = $('.namebox').val();
         var email = $('.namebox2').val();
         var message = $('.namebox3').val();


            $.ajax({
               type:'post',
               url:'/sendbasicemail',
               data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, name: name, email: email, message: message},
               dataType: 'JSON',
               success:function(data){
                   alert("DONE"); 
                  console.log(data);
                  },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, request) { 
                     alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                      console.log(name, email, message);

                 }    
             });
         }
      </script>
   </head>



<ul>
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>


{!! Form::open() !!}

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
{!! Form::label('Name:') !!}
{!! Form::text('name', '',['class'=>'namebox', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Name']) !!}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
{!! Form::label('Email:') !!}
{!! Form::text('email', '',['class'=>'namebox2', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Email']) !!}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('message') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
{!! Form::label('Message:') !!}
{!! Form::textarea('message', '',['class'=>'namebox3', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Message']) !!}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('message') }}</span>
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}

   <body>
      <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
         Click the button to replace the message.</div>
      <?php
         echo Form::button('Replace',['onClick'=>'getMessage()']);
      ?>
   </body>

</html>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/ajax',function(){
   return view('pages.contact');
}); 
Route::post('/sendbasicemail','EmailController@basic_email');
```

On a side note I have tried some outside so you may notice some differences

Comment: why you validating from two methods first one is using validate class and other one form request class . Only pass ContactFormRequest Request in controller instead of Request

Comment: I had a issue where it popped "Error: Unprocessable Entity" only with the name field untill I added the new request.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit messy i suggest to check your `contact.blade.php` your html tags sequence is not correct , 
i see form tags outside the body tag and submit button outside the form tag.

Here i tried to re-organize your view file :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>

      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

      <script> 
         function getMessage(){

         var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
         var name = $('.namebox').val();
         var email = $('.namebox2').val();
         var message = $('.namebox3').val();


            $.ajax({
               type:'post',
               url:'/sendbasicemail',
               data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, name: name, email: email, message: message},
               dataType: 'JSON',
               success:function(data){
                   alert("DONE"); 
                  console.log(data);
                  },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, request) { 
                     alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                      console.log(name, email, message);

                 }    
             });
         }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>

        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>


        {!! Form::open() !!}

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {!! Form::label('Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', '',['class'=>'namebox', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Name']) !!}
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {!! Form::label('Email:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('email', '',['class'=>'namebox2', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Email']) !!}
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('message') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {!! Form::label('Message:') !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('message', '',['class'=>'namebox3', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Message']) !!}
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('message') }}</span>
            </div>

            <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
                Click the button to replace the message.</div>
            <?php
                echo Form::button('Replace',['onClick'=>'getMessage()']);
            ?>
        {!! Form::close() !!}

   </body>
</html>
```

However "Error: Unprocessable Entity" is an error generally caused if you pass data in your Ajax request without serializing it or your data is not validated in server side

Comment: Yeah it got a bit messy with me tearing and changing a lot, thanks

Comment: Yeah, but that's because the fields need the correct field data. The issue i'm truly stuck on is the internal 500

Comment: What ```laravel.log``` says ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue sorted.

Had to change the controllers variables as it was posting a object with special characters.